# Starting Realm Object server on AWS stalls

Tags: amazon-ec2, realm

I've been trying to use Realm Object Server deployed on an Amazon ec2 instance, using the basic Amazon Ubuntu AMI (since the Realm AMI has ROS v.1.8.3).

To use the latest ROS (v2.x) I followed Realm's instructions to use `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/realm/realm-object-server/master/install.sh | bash` which appears to execute successfully. I follow that script's instructions to load nvm and use its latest version.

Then I run `ros start`. Here's what I get:

```
info: Loaded feature token capabilities=[Sync], expires=Wed Apr 19 2017 14:15:29 GMT+0000 (UTC)
info: Realm Object Server version 2.0.18 is starting
info: [sync] Realm sync server started ([realm-core-4.0.3], [realm-sync-2.1.4])
info: [sync] Directory holding persistent state: /home/ubuntu/data/sync/user_data
info: [sync] Operating mode: master_with_no_slave
info: [sync] Log level: info
info: [sync] Download log compaction is enabled
info: [sync] Max download size: 131072 bytes
info: [sync] Listening on 127.0.0.1:40134 (sync protocol version 22)
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__wildcardpermissions HTTP/1.1 200 55 - 56.996 ms
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__password HTTP/1.1 200 44 - 53.009 ms
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__perm HTTP/1.1 200 40 - 9.402 ms
info: Autocreated admin user: realm-admin
info: Realm Object Server has started and is listening on http://0.0.0.0:9080
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__admin HTTP/1.1 200 41 - 4.187 ms
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__admin HTTP/1.1 200 41 - 29.902 ms
```

And then...nothing. It doesn't even get me back to my `ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:` prompt. (It's possible that this is exactly what you'd expect but I'm pretty new to these kind of processes).

When I try to access my server in the browser (my DNS:9080) the browser says `Cannot GET /` and the CLI says `info: [http] 96.2xx.xxx.xxx - GET / HTTP/1.1 404 139 - 0.521 ms`

The security groups for my ec2 instance are:

```
HTTP / TCP / 80 / 0.0.0.0/0
SSH / TCP / 22 / 0.0.0.0/0
Custom UDP Rule / UDP / 9080 / 0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule / TCP / 9080 / 0.0.0.0/0
```

I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The web based dashboard was part of ROS 1.x, but was replaced by [Realm Studio](https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/) in ROS 2.0.